# For Loop Dependent on Number Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I'm trying to repeat a div, the number of times dependent on the number chosen in a number input field, but currently when the number input is changed the values are being multiplied. So if you go from 2 to 3 it repeats the div 6 times instead of just 3. How can I reset the loop so it's using only the current number?

http://jsfiddle.net/deliciouslycheesy/6rb94mry/

```
$('#numRepeat').on('change keyup input', function () {  
  var el = $(".repeat-me").get(0);
  var numRepeat = $("#numRepeat").val();

  for(var i = 1;i < numRepeat;i++){    
    var newEl = $(el).after(el.cloneNode(true));   
  }
}).change();
```

Comment: why are you calling `change()` at the end of the event handler?

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Presumably to trigger the event initially so that the number of elements reflects the input value on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the ones that were added before:

```js
$('#numRepeat').bind('change keyup input', function () {
 var el = $(".repeat-me").get(0);
  $(".repeat-me:not(:first)").remove();
 var numRepeat = $("#numRepeat").val();
  
  for(var i = 1;i < numRepeat;i++){    
    var newEl = $(el).after(el.cloneNode(true));   
 }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="numRepeat" value="2"/>
<div class="repeat-me">REPEAT</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bo4rowbc/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using three event `change keyup input`, just `input` event will detect changes inside `input` field, check the **[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rb94mry/3/)**.

I suggest to separate the model of repeated `div` from the result, i think that will make code more clear, and because you're using JQuery you can replace `cloneNode()` by `clone()`.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('#numRepeat').on('input', function () {
    var el = $("#model-div .repeat-me");
    var numRepeat = $(this).val();
  
    $('#result-div').empty(); //Clear the result div
    
    for(var i = 0 ; i < numRepeat ; i++)
    {    
       $('#result-div').append( $(el).clone(true) );
    }
})
```

```css
#model-div{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="numRepeat" value="0"/>

<div id="model-div">
    <div class="repeat-me">REPEAT</div>
</div>

<div id="result-div"></div>
```